# Is it possible to write a java program from TOAD?

Tags: java, toad

I am using TOAD for ORACLE application.
I am playing around with data and tables.

My manager has asked me to experiment if one can write a Java program from TOAD.
You can always write a standalone java program in eclipse and make some jdbc connections and get it executed.

But is it possible to run a Java program from TOAD itself?
If so how?

Comment: Ah, managers. Please push him/her in to a wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really a reasonable thing to do in order to write a full fledged java program, no.

If you just want to use Java Stored Procedures in Oracle, then yes it does help there.  It'll do syntax highlighting and has pretty good debugging features as well.